# Is it possible to use Hyper-V Server 2012 Core monitors to log into guest machines?

Tags: hyper-v

I have a machine with two video monitors I want to use for running the Hyper-V Server 2012 Core. Is there any way possible that I can use one or both monitors on the Hyper-V machine itself, for logging into the guest virtual machines? Sometimes I want to access the guests while at the machine and not from another computer.

Thanks, Dave

Comment: No it is not but I clarified. I"m not trying to RDP to Hyper-V from a dual monitor system, I want to use one or both of the monitors ON the Hyper-V system to logon to the guests.

Comment: Ignore the part about two monitors. Is there anyway I can use one of the monitors on the Hyper-V core machine to talk to one of the guests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Core hypervisor has no GUI, so there's no GUI console to use.  The intention of Core is to be a minimal hypervisor, VM connections are intended to be done from remote (via RDP).

If you want a GUI on the host (ie: to interact with the VMs), then use a full version of Server 2012 as the host OS. If you're using it ONLY with the Hyper-V host role, then you can use a single licence as both the host and a guest VM.

Comment: No doubt the answer here, and I will mark as such soon. I was just hoping for some sort of core addin that would let me use the physical monitors for a guest rather than RDP in, for this particular machine. Thx.

Comment: I have used Win Server 2008 R2 in this scenario before but was hoping to not have a server installed, just desktop OS' - seems all the type 1 hypervisors would be greatly more useful if added some client connection via the local consoles, as they would greatly expand their usage in advanced desktop scenarios. I just don't want type 2 hypers for this as I want the desktop OS usage to be more flexible where I can swap VHD/VMDKs in and out there and elsewhere w/o having to maintain one of the images as the primary OS for the type 2 host.